# Launching Eclipse debug mode from terminal, Pydev

Tags: eclipse, terminal, runtime, pydev

Let say I have a working Eclipse project .  The debug configuration is set up correctly such that I can launch Eclipse and start debug mode with a few clicks.  No other run time input is needed and a breakpoint is already added to the beginning of the program.

Instead of clicking, I want to know if there is a way that I can do this from a terminal.  Basically I want to script the command.  I've found the options to disable splashdown and select the workspace.  The Eclipse version is Luna.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the properties of the process that's in the Debug view when you start it from there. Also: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for in the Debug view.  Could you be a little more specific?  Also I've seen the runtime options, nothing stands out that indicates "start and run".  Thanks.

Comment: Find the node in the tree that actually represents the running Java executable. Its Properties dialog will let you see the full command line that was invoked to start it.

Comment: I found something in Debug that kinda fits to what you're saying.  So it's a long Python command...  But with that command alone I wouldn't be able to start Eclipse and kick off Pydev.  Overcome by event, I may not need a solution for this but thanks for your help nitind.